# Dalaran doesn't load right

Tags: technical-issues, world-of-warcraft

I was wondering if anyone had problems with loading screen with Legion?
I run WoW on a good PC (GTX 1070 and i5) and my internet connection is good, but since Legion my loading screens are really long and sometimes I even have to relaunch the game for it to work.

Did someone had this problem and if yes, did you found a solution?

Comment: We have an issue with our first loading screen of the day taking forever.
Are all loading screens long or just the first like ours?

Comment: I always have the issue when loading Dalaran even if I was already in game, and it does it for others loading screen like those to go to Pandarie. So pretty much all the loading screens (some are really critical and need to restart the game)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many people have been reporting this problem since the release of patch 7.1.

It is an issue on Blizzard's side and there isn't really a permanent solution that works for everybody right now, however there are many forum threads with some temporary fixes.

From the **[megathread](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/20749718759?page=1)** about the issue:

> Howdy!
>
> Our developers have pushed a hot fix that is aimed to significantly
>   alleviate long load times. Anyone still seeing long load times, we
>   would like you to use the following cvar command:
>
> Step 1) Goto the World of Warcraft tab within the Battle.net Desktop
>   app -> Options -> Show in Explorer -> World of Warcraft -> WTF -> Open
>   the Config.wtf file with notepad add the line: SET
>   worldPreloadNonCritical “0” Save the document.
>
> It's important that you restart the computer before retesting.
>
> Note: Please be aware this command may cause a delay in loading of non
>   critical environment textures and models.
>
> Step 2) While we're hoping to avoid this step, at all costs. Our
>   developers feel pretty strongly that with the hotfix and this command
>   this issue should be greatly improved. At this point if the
>   troubleshooting so far including step 1 has no impact on your load
>   times. We would ask you to do a fresh reinstall of the client by
>   following the steps [Here](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/uninstalling-games-with-the-battlenet-app).
>
> Thank you!

**[Original Bluepost](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/20749718759?page=151#post-3014)**

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I'll try that later and will tell you if the first step worked, hoping that I will not have to re download all the game ...

Comment: When opening the Config.wtf I don't have a line "worldPreloadNonCritical"

Comment: @Ise It says "add the line".

Comment: You should not copy and paste directly from that blue post, or you will get stupid "smart" quotes that will break your config.wtf. It should instead read: `SET worldPreloadNonCritical "0"`  (which _is_ safe to copy and paste).

Comment: Ah ok sorry I was expecting to find a line at first.

Comment: Adding the line didn't worked nor did re downloading the game :/
But as you say if it comes from Blizzard then I'm just going to validate your answer and hope that a patch will come out.